# Thunderbird - Set Sent folder address

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I have a pretty nasty problem with Thunderbird in the moment:

On my IMAP Mailserver I have a folder called "Gesendete Objekte" which corresponds to "Sent Items". This is the location for all sent mail and cannot be changed.

Thunderbird has the default address for Sent at the folder "Sent" on the server, which in my case does not exist.

I haven't found any way to change this, even setting the path in the about:config does not change the folders address.

Thunderbird currently has the Folder "Sent" grayed out and shows "Sent Items" as a separate folder - I want to have "Sent" set to the correct path and simply not show "Sent Items" via not subscribing to it.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In Accounts Settings, Copies and Folders, there is an option to say where sent items go.

Answer (score 0):

Install a TB addon called "Folder Flags" by Ryan Lee (http://ryanlee.org/software/mozilla/thunderbird/folderflags/) which allows to set/clear the flag which makes a folder "special" like Sent, Inbox, Drafts etc.
Note that there is a bug in TB which makes TB recreate special folders in POP3 accounts, and that the Trash folder needs special handling (all info on Ryan's website).